# I want to return a multidimensional array depending on values within nested arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm building a search function in react-native and redux.  In my action creator, I'm returning a json from Firebase.  I then turn json into an array:

```
 const myObj = snapshot.val(); //json 
 const array1 = Object.entries(myObj).map(function(key) {
    return (key);
  });
```

That way I can filter() through array1.

```
const array2 = array1.filter(
    (value) => {
      const element = "John Deere"; // I've hard coded the user input 

    return (value.indexOf(element) !== -1);
  });
```

However, array1 is a multi-dimensional array.  So, this filter() doesn't have access to the nested array.  If I create an array copy1 like so, it will have access:

```
  const copy1 = [];
  const len = array1.length;
  for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  copy1.push(array1[i][1]);
  }
```

But then I lose access to

```
array1[i][0].
```

That index is a unique id created by Firebase. Which I need to make sure my data doesn't get all mixed up.

Is there a way to .filter() a specific index of an array (array1[i][1]), but to return the full array where that specific index matches the criteria?

```
(array1 [i] where array1 [i][1] matches the user input(element))
```

I can't just return:

```
array1 [i][j]
```

because array1 [i][0] is just a string and not an object (key value pair), so that causes an error.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `filter()`

Change:

```
return (value.indexOf(element) !== -1);
```

To

```
return (value[specifiedIndex].indexOf(element) !== -1);
```

OR

```
return value[specifiedIndex].includes(element);
```

Comment: charlietfl  You are a rockstar!  With this code I'm able to access the Firebase id: const array2 = array1.filter(
        (value) => {
          const element = "-KzPj2RoB0CatW_vpfwq";
          for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
         return (value[i].indexOf(element) !== -1);
       }
      });          My array is structured like this: 
0
:
"-KzPj2RoB0CatW_vpfwq"
1
:
{make: "John Deere", model: "4010", year: "1958"}     Setting element to "John Deere" however returns an empty array.  Why can't I access the objects in index 1?

Comment: Try `value[specifiedIndex].make.includes(element)` . That assumes you know the property name you want to search and filter by

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked:

```
const array2 = array1.filter(
    (value) => {
      const element = "John Deere";
      for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
     return (value[1].make.indexOf(element) !== -1);
       }
     });
```

That is of course only going to work for the "make" key.  But I'm sure it's possible to use the || operator in the filter function to include more keys.